# Force fullscreen mode in Chrome for Android

Tags: chrome-for-android

I want to put my Chrome browser in fullscreen mode without having to scroll down first.

Is it possible? Alternatively, are there any browsers that have this feature?

If it matters, my device is a Samsung Galaxy Tab E, Android 4.4.2. Not rooted.

Comment: See https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-enable-system-wide-immersive-mode-without-root/

Comment: I think there are 2 possible interpretations of "full screen" for this question: (1) Android's immersive mode (hide notification bar and navigation bar), or (2) Chrome's full screen (hide address bar). From the original wording of "having to scroll down first", looks like it's more about Chrome's full screen than Android's immersive mode, though fulfilling both is the most ideal...

Comment: Related: [Force browser to hide nav & tab bar](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/132612/44325)

Answer (score 16):

Yes, you can do it by just running a line of JavaScript on the webpage. To do so, you can just type in the URL bar this code:

```
javascript: (function(){document.querySelector("body").requestFullscreen();})();
```

To avoid typing this manually, you can add this as a bookmarklet. For this, you have to just add any page in your bookmarks and edit the URL to the code above. After bookmarking, search for it in the url bar and you will be able to run the code.

Comment: This is awesome. I added this code as a Bookmark called FS. Then I just type FS in the address and then I tap in the second result which is the bookmark  it's the fastest way I can think of having a Fullscreen navigation whenever I need

Comment: Does this work in Android 13?  My experiments led me to learn about this important requirement:  [Features gated by user activation ...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/User_activation)

Answer (score 5):

There is a [great article in How-To Geek on how to force that for any app with Chrome as sample](https://www.howtogeek.com/302194/how-to-force-any-android-app-into-fullscreen-immersive-mode-without-rooting/). It's difficult for non-technical people though.

The approach is to execute a command from a connected computer to put chrome on a "full-screen state". You must connect the tablet via USB-Cable to the PC. I paste the steps for accessibility here:

- Enable USB debugging on Android.
- Install the Android SDK and ADB on PC.
- Find Your App’s APK Name *(Something like “com.android.chrome.”)*
- Verify Your Device Connection with ADB
- Choose Your Immersive Mode (Command line)

This is the command to be executed from the connected PC:

```
adb shell settings put global policy_control immersive.full=com.android.chrome
```

Detailed instructions can be found in the source article.

Answer (score 2):

Settings > display > expanded desktop

That works on lineageOS, but last time I told someone to looks here, they said their phone didn't have it.

Comment: No such option exists anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with Chrome, at least not in current point in time.

Since you said another browser with that feature will also help:

**There were comments (thanks) about the fact that it's really outdated, and probably has some security issues, so it's not really recommended.**

## [Full Screen Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tk.klurige.fullscreenbrowser&hl=en)

**From the app page:**

> Web browser that allows for full screen viewing.
> Used in many kiosk applications and similar products.
>
> - Hide or dim navigation bar (Home, Back etc).
> - Hide Action bar.
> - Hide status bar.
>
> Support for desktop and mobile versions of web pages.
>
> [image]

Comment: This app hasn't gotten any updates in 6 years, absolutely not useful. An extreme security risk.

Comment: People even complain about SSL problems using it- Not recommended!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why chrome doesn't give a option for fullscreen mode.

But you can view a webpage totally fullscreen using another browser such as

1. Brave
2. Full screen browser
3. Samsung browser
4. Mozilla Firefox browser

All the above browsers are in google play store.

Comment: No, you can't. Not in brave.

Comment: You can't in samsung or brave, Firefox is the only one that fullscreens for me yet it's broken with my webapp so I need a chromium fullscreen app

Comment: Chrome running on Android, unlike on Windows desktop, does not want to run in sustained full-screen mode for some reason:  [Features gated by user activation ...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/User_activation)

Answer (score 1):

If you only need fullscreen for a specific site:

1. Open the site in Android Chrome
2. Tap the menu (3 dots at upper right) and choose "Add to Home Screen"
3. It will prompt you to change the title. Tap Ok.
4. Go to your phone's home screen and you should now see a new icon for the site. It opens in full screen like a separate app. (Since my home screen was almost full, the new icon got dumped into a new home screen reachable by swiping left on the main home screen.)

Comment: Nope. No, it doesn't

Comment: This solution works fine for me on an Android tablet using Chrome.

Comment: Doesn't do a thing

Comment: No longer works. I remember this working before, Google must have removed it from Chrome.