# How to view a web page in full screen?

Tags: browser, notification-bar, navigation-bar

I want to use my old phone as a dashboard for Home Assistant. To do this I would like to view a web page in full screen.

With full screen I mean only show the web page itself with **no address bar**, **no status / notification bar** and **no navigation / buttons bar**. So completely full screen. Just like with full screen videos or games.

Is there a way to do this?

I don't care about which browser though I prefer Chrome. As long as it's able to run JS and to stay logged in and such.

It is a Pocophone F1 running Android 10 if that helps. It's not rooted, but I'm willing to do that if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Force browser to hide nav & tab bar](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/132612/44325), [Force fullscreen mode in Chrome for Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/175329/44325)

Comment: Yes the answer is in there: using Fully Kiosk Browser Thank you very much!

Comment: Good to know! I'll close the question as a dupe of them then.